# Use reified constraints to make 3 numbers consecutive

Tags: prolog, constraints, clpfd

Here's an outline of my SWI-Prolog program:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

consec1(L) :-
   L=[L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7,L8,L9],
   L ins 1..9,
   ...,
   abs(L5-L4)#=1,
   all_different(L),
   labeling([],L)
```

`abs(L5-L4)#=1` makes `L5` and `L4` next to each other. If I wanted to make three numbers next to each other e.g. `L3`, `L4` and `L5`, how could I use reified constraints to do this?

E.g. `L3=4`,`L5=5`,`L4=6` or `L4=7`,`L5=8`,`L3=9`

Comment: With 'consecutive', do you mean e.g. `(L2#=L1+1 #/\ L3#=L2+1) #\/ (L2#=L1-1 #/\ L3#=L2-1)`?

Comment: Also, should that relation hold for all 3 adjacent members of L---or just for some/any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implements consecutive in the sense you gave in the comments. For a list of `N` values, we need space enough to make all the values fit in between, and all values need to be different.

```
consecutive([]).  % debatable case
consecutive(Xs) :-
   Xs = [_|_],
   length(Xs, N),
   all_different(Xs),
   max_of(Max, Xs),
   min_of(Min, Xs),
   Max-Min #= N-1.

max_of(Max, [Max]).
max_of(Max0, [E|Es]) :-
   Max0 #= max(E,Max1),
   max_of(Max1, Es).

min_of(Min, [Min]).
min_of(Min0, [E|Es]) :-
   Min0 #= min(E, Min1),
   min_of(Min1, Es).
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** too long for a comment: play-time with specialized [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraints

---

This answer follows up [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30112309/4609915); recent versions of SICStus Prolog offer specialized clpfd constraints `maximum/2` and `minimum/2` as alternatives to `min_of/2` and `max_of/2`.

Using the following code for benchmarking<sup>1,2</sup> ...

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(between)).

bench_(How, N, Ub) :-
   \+ \+ ( length(Xs, N),
           domain(Xs, 1, Ub),
           all_different(Xs),
           Max-Min #= N-1,
           (  How = 0
           ;  How = min_of , max_of( Max, Xs), min_of( Min, Xs)
           ;  How = minimum, maximum(Max, Xs), minimum(Min, Xs)
           ),
           labeling([enum], Xs) ).
```

... we run the following tests:

1. To estimate worst-case overhead of min/max constraint:

   ```
   ?- member(How, [0,v1,v2]), call_time(bench_(How,10,10), T_ms).
      How = 0 , T_ms =  5910
   ;  How = v1, T_ms = 19560
   ;  How = v2, T_ms =  7190.
   ```
2. To measure the runtime costs of propagating min/max constraints in more typical cases:

   ```
   ?- between(6, 8, N), NN #= N+N, call_time(bench_(v1,N,NN),T_ms).
      N = 6, NN = 12, T_ms =   50 
   ;  N = 7, NN = 14, T_ms =  300
   ;  N = 8, NN = 16, T_ms = 2790.

   ?- between(6, 8, N), NN #= N+N, call_time(bench_(v2,N,NN),T_ms).
      N = 6, NN = 12, T_ms =   20
   ;  N = 7, NN = 14, T_ms =  100
   ;  N = 8, NN = 16, T_ms =  830.
   ```

In both "use cases", the specialized constraints give impressive speedup.

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** Using SICStus Prolog version 4.3.2 (64-bit).

**Footnote 2:** Answer sequences were post-processed to improve appearance.</sup>